# Changing label position of data point in plot

Tags: r, plot

I have plotted some datapoints with plot function together with a Duncan's multiple range test. When i change the limits of the y-axis the grouping label of the first datapoint exceeds the plot and can no longer be seen.

How can i reduce the spacing between the datapoint and label?

My code:

```
data(FILIPPA)
model<-aov(TA~DATO + GE,data=FILIPPA)
out <- duncan.test(model,"DATO", 
               main="Syre i Filippa")
plot(out,variation="IQR", ylim=c(7,9.5), )
duncan.test(model,"DATO",alpha=0.05,console=TRUE)
```

Comment: where can the FILIPPA data be found?

Comment: Here is my problem ![R-plot](https://imgur.com/a/ciKbc) I will try uploading my excel file

Comment: try to add this before you plot: ```par(mar = c(5,5,10,1))```

Comment: ![FILIPPA-data](https://file.io/ELEXMM)

Comment: Unfortunately, the margin function does not fix it, it just resizes the plot box in R

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the FILIPPA dataset (apples and titratable acidity?).
But maybe the graphical parameter `xpd` is what you're looking for?

It doesn't look like `plot.group()` allows for adjusting the position of the labels.

[image]

```
library(agricolae)
data(mtcars)

model <- aov(mpg ~ wt + cyl, data=mtcars)
out <- duncan.test(model,"cyl", main="Fuel efficiency")

par(xpd=TRUE, mar=c(2, 2, 3, 1))
plot(out, variation="IQR", ylim=c(13, 30))
duncan.test(model, "cyl", alpha=0.05, console=TRUE)
```